# Preety print JSP output

Tags: jsp, tomcat

I have the following jsp

```
 <jsp:root xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" 
          xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
 version="2.0">

 <jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8" />
 <jsp:output omit-xml-declaration="true" />
 <jsp:output doctype-root-element="html" doctype-system="about:legacy-compat"/>

 <html lang="en">
  <head>
   <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
   <title>HTML5</title>
  </head>
  <body>
   <h1>HTML5</h1>
  </body>
 </html>

</jsp:root>
```

And the default tomcat7 generated html looks like

```
<!DOCTYPE html SYSTEM "about:legacy-compat">
<html lang="en"><head><meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="content-type"/><title>HTML5</title></head><body><h1>HTML5</h1></body></html>
```

I would like it to be preety printed(just better for debugging)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
  <meta name="generator" content=
  "HTML Tidy for Linux/x86 (vers 11 February 2007), see www.w3.org" />
  <meta content="text/html; charset=us-ascii" http-equiv="content-type" />

  <title>HTML5</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>HTML5</h1>
</body>
```

I guess if I wrote the same page as html and named it as jsp it would retain it's format and I could still use jsp tage.

Comment: Yes XHTML/JSPX parser does this.  Have you read https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jasper-howto.html and seen trimSpaces (in 2 places) ?  You setup a servlet called `jsp` in web.xml with these settings.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're having is that you're using the XML version of JSP, rather than typical JSP. That's why all of your whitespace is being consumed.

You could either convert over to normal JSP, or you could add a filter that consumes the entire content, and then reformats it. The latter isn't trivial, but it's not super difficult either.